# updating a table involving groupby clause while avoiding temp tables

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I have a transaction log table that is updated each time a record is updated.

```
autoid ID Date        Source
1       1 2010-10-11  abc
2       2 2010-09-10  xyz
3       1 2010-08-03  pqr
4       1 2010-11-01  mno
```

I can get the most recent update for each ID by the following query (it is efficient, is it?):

```
select * from mytable group by ID order by Date desc;
```

Now if I have another table that should be updated with the most recent transaction date, how do I go about doing it without creating a temp table?

The following query is incorrect, but is there a nested query alternative? I don't want to create a temp table.

```
update mytable a, othertable b
set b.date = a.date
where b.ID = a.ID group by ID order by Date desc;
```

ajreal's solution worked!

```
update othertable,
(select b.id, max(b.`date`) as latest from mytable b group by b.id) as b
set othertable.`date` = b.latest
where othertable.id=b.id
;
```

Comment: add in index on ID + Date should help,
without knowing the size of the table and u seems to SELECT * without LIMIT ... is kind of not efficient, the UPDATE statement is wrong due to lack of table alias in GROUP BY

Comment: This table I am working on returns 700 rows, hence the no limit. So a table alias should make group by work in update query? Could you please chalk out a sample query? I generally stay out of complicated queries but temp tables is something I kind of hate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update mytable,
(select b.id, max(b.`date`) as latest from othertable b group by b.id) as b
set mytable.`date`=b.latest
where mytable.id=b.id
;
```

Comment: I tried this but it is throwing an error. I had to replace mytable with othertable since I am updating othertable with data from mytable.

Comment: create table mytable (autoid integer primary key auto_increment, id integer, `date` date, source varchar(3));

insert into mytable (id, `date`, source) VALUES (10,curdate()-1,'test'), (11,curdate()-5,'test'), (10,curdate()-3,'test');

create table othertable like mytable;

insert into othertable (id) VALUES (10),(11);

Comment: notice few problems 1. curdate()-n can be replaced to date_add(curdate(), interval n day) 2. char length for source is too small

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, I really appreciate it! It worked! (had to replace mytable with othertable in your query)